# Stata loop to retrieve data from Excel file

Tags: excel, loops, stata, stata-macros, readstata13

My Excel file has many sheets. I am trying to create a loop to retrieve every sheet of data to be able to save it as .dta. This is my code:

```
local sheet = `" "Data dictionary" "Wave 1" "Wave 2" "Wave 3" "Wave 4" "'

foreach x of local sheets{
     import excel "/Users/a/Downloads/EVSdata.xlsx", sheet("`x'") 
     save "/Users/a/Downloads/sheet_`x’.dta"
}
```

The output does not show any error but it does not save the data either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good attempt, but there are a few small syntax errors in your code. Note the subtle differences in this code:

```
local sheet = `" "Data dictionary" "Wave 1" "Wave 2" "Wave 3" "Wave 4" "'

foreach x in `sheet' {
     import excel "mydata.xlsx", sheet("`x'") clear
     save "sheet_`x'.dta", replace
}
```